# The file is damaged and could not be repaired

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to display a PDF file in my ASP.net page based on the binary data received from the ASP.net Web service. Below is the code. though I am getting the data from the Web Service for some reason, if I run the below mentioned code on page load I am getting the above mentioned error.

Please help

```
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Inline")

Dim ws As New imageGenService.Service1
Dim imagebyte As Byte() = Nothing

imagebyte = ws.generateSamplePDF()

If imagebyte IsNot Nothing Then
    '"attachment; filename=Whatever.pdf"

    Dim MemStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim doc As New iTextSharp.text.Document
    Dim reader As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader
    Dim numberOfPages As Integer
    Dim currentPageNumber As Integer
    Dim writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, MemStream)
    doc.Open()
    Dim cb As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
    Dim page As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage
    Dim rotation As Integer

    reader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(imagebyte)
    numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages
    currentPageNumber = 0

    Do While (currentPageNumber < numberOfPages)
        currentPageNumber += 1
        doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER)
        doc.NewPage()
        page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageNumber)
        rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(currentPageNumber)
        If (rotation = 90) Or (rotation = 270) Then
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageNumber).Height)
        Else
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0)
        End If

    Loop

    If MemStream Is Nothing Then
        Response.Write("No Data is available for output")
    Else
        Response.BinaryWrite(MemStream.GetBuffer())
    End If



End If
```

When I open the PDF in a notepad below is the following I see:

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Untitled Page
</title></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="ShowPDF.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNzgzNDMwNTMzZGQpkGvp7bYOLIE6xshhcZ2kYd2baA==" />
</div>

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is continuing to render your aspx website code in the response because you haven't called [Response.End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524629.aspx) to prevent further processing.  Add a call to that method in after you've completed your binary write - your PDF render code will end up as:

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Inline")
    Response.BinaryWrite(MemStream.GetBuffer())
    Response.Flush
    Response.End
```

**EDIT:**
In addition, I think that you may not be creating your PDF document correctly - see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186817/itextsharp-filestream-corrupt-pdf-file).  The important step that I think you might have missed is to close the document by calling `doc.Close` before you attempt to read from it (that is, immediately after the loop where you add your content).

Comment: Dexter, After putting response.end I still get the same error and if I open the PDF in notepad I see the below %PDF-1.4 %粤ﾏﾓ

Comment: @acadia - did adding a call to doc.Close fix your problem?

Comment: It's better to use CompleteRequest() instead of Response.End() which exists only for Classic ASP compatibility. See these blogs http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/use-httpapplication-completerequest-instead-of-response-end/ or  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. Tried all the suggestions. Did not work until finally tried specifying the content-length and voila!

Hope this reply is help after 1 year.

Add this code:

Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", MemStream.GetBuffer().Length)

Comment: Works perfectly.Thanks. My issue was that I was using HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() instead of Response.End(). Setting the Content-Length header fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the content-length header equal to the size of the MemoryStream. In addition, try calling Response.Flush after your call to Response.BinaryWrite.

Comment: It didn't work in psite of setting the content length and response.flush