# PDFium - create PDF document from image stream without converting to Bitmap in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, memorystream, pdfium

I am working with [PDFium c#](https://pdfium.patagames.com/) tool to create PDF document from PNG image stream.

I have an API which gets multiple image stream objects, I should combine the image streams and create a PDF document and PDF stream. I will need to hit another API to save this document.

I went through the [PDFium documentation](https://pdfium.patagames.com/) but, the examples shows how load PDF from Images but, not from stream

Do we need to create a image from Stream to load the PDF or is there any alternate?

Any help is highly appreciated

Thank you In advance

Sample Code I created based on the documentation

```
public void GeneratePdfFromImageStream(List<Stream> imageStreams, String pdfSaveLocation = null)
    {
        int pageIndex = 0;
        //Initialize C# PDF Library
        PdfCommon.Initialize();
        //Create a PDF document
        using (var doc = PdfDocument.CreateNew())
        {

            foreach (var imageStream in imageStreams)
            {

                //I am creating a Bitmap image here, is there a way I can achevie the same withrout creating the image 
                 var image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(imageStream, true) as System.Drawing.Bitmap;

                //Create empty PdfBitmap
                using (PdfBitmap pdfBitmap = new PdfBitmap(image.Width, image.Height, true))
                {
                    using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(pdfBitmap.Image))
                    {
                        //Draw image to PdfBitmap
                        g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
                    }
                    //Create Image object
                    var imageObject = PdfImageObject.Create(doc, pdfBitmap, 0, 0);
                    //Calculate size of image in PDF points
                    var size = CalculateSize(pdfBitmap.Width, pdfBitmap.Height, image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
                    //Add empty page to PDF document
                    doc.Pages.InsertPageAt(pageIndex, size);
                    //Insert image to newly created page
                    doc.Pages[pageIndex].PageObjects.Add(imageObject);
                    //set image matrix
                    imageObject.Matrix = new FS_MATRIX(size.Width, 0, 0, size.Height, 0, 0);
                    //Generate PDF page content to content stream
                    doc.Pages[pageIndex].GenerateContent();
                    pageIndex++;
                }
            }
            // Save  PDF document as "saved.pdf" in no incremental mode
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pdfSaveLocation))
                doc.Save($"saved_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.pdf", SaveFlags.NoIncremental);
        }

    }
```