# iTextSharp-generated PDFs cause save dialog when closing

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am using iTextSharp to generate PDF documents, and save them to disk like this:

```
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 80, 50);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Ruta, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        PdfWriter PDFWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);

        EsquemaFormato PageEventHandler = new EsquemaFormato();
        PageEventHandler.Title = TitleMiddle;
        PageEventHandler.TitleHeaderFont = FontFactory.GetFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, 12, Font.NORMAL);
        PageEventHandler.TitleRightHeaderFont = FontFactory.GetFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, 9, Font.NORMAL);
        PageEventHandler.HeaderLeft = "Nombre";
        PageEventHandler.HeaderRight = TitleRight;
        PageEventHandler.RutaImagen = RutaImagen;
        PageEventHandler.Cuerpo = Cuerpo;
        PDFWriter.PageEvent = PageEventHandler;

        document.Open();
        document.Close();
```

Based on http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx

I open any PDF file I just created, but when I try to close it causes a "Do you want to Save?" dialog to appear. This does not happen with PDFs that are not generated with iTextSharp.

What am I missing? I've seen solutions using Response but I don´t use it.
Thanks in advance.

Update:
Here is a sample http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4582874/test.pdf

EDIT:
By following Bruno's link I found this post: [iTextSharp + FileStream = Corrupt PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186817/itextsharp-filestream-corrupt-pdf-file)

That did the trick!
Here is my working code now:

```
    public void CreatePDF(string TitleMiddle, string Ruta, string RutaImagen, string TitleRight, string Cuerpo)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 80, 50);
            PdfWriter PDFWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

            EsquemaFormato PageEventHandler = new EsquemaFormato();
            PageEventHandler.Title = TitleMiddle;
            PageEventHandler.TitleHeaderFont = FontFactory.GetFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, 12, Font.NORMAL);
            PageEventHandler.TitleRightHeaderFont = FontFactory.GetFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, 9, Font.NORMAL);
            PageEventHandler.HeaderLeft = "Nombre";
            PageEventHandler.HeaderRight = TitleRight;
            PageEventHandler.RutaImagen = RutaImagen;
            PageEventHandler.Cuerpo = Cuerpo;
            PDFWriter.PageEvent = PageEventHandler;

            document.Open();
            document.Close();
            byte[] content = ms.ToArray();
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Ruta))
            {
                fs.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also post a sample pdf generated by your code for further inspection?

Comment: Duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569475/using-itextsharp-to-write-data-to-pdf-works-great-but-acrobat-reader-asks-do-y/12586773

Comment: Bruno, I'm not using GetBuffer()

Comment: mkl, how can I post a sample pdf here? I can't find an attach file option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it without the FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite properties?

I create PDF's using itextSharp everyday and have never ran into this issue - main difference between your code and mine is i don't have these.

I suspect the FileShare is leaving the document somewhat open, waiting for someone to finalise closing it with a save?

Comment: FileStream fs = new FileStream(Ruta, FileMode.OpenOrCreate); // i get the same problem

Comment: close your filestream too. either that or create the new filestream inline with your GetInstance. PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Ruta, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

Comment: It worked too (i'd already edited my post with another solution), thanks!